# Multiple Javascript functions embedded in html

Tags: javascript, html, slider, label

I am trying to implement two sliders in HTML and use Javascript functions to update the indicator of the values of those sliders. I don't know how to structure the code for the output of each slider. I think there is a problem with the way that the Javascript codes are embedded. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Purpose: Have two sliders with two separate indicators in HTML

Thanks!

```html
<body>

<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange1">
  <p>Value1: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
</div>


</body>

<head>
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output = document.getElementById("demo1");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>




</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating the code, taking into account the introduction of small changes - is bad.

I made you a js code with the `forEach()` method. This means that now you can control many `input` without having to write js logic for every.

Just replace your js code with this one:

```
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.slidecontainer input');
let result = document.querySelectorAll('.slidecontainer span');

input.forEach(function(input_current, index) {
  input_current.oninput = function() {
    result[index].innerHTML = this.value;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variables in separate `script` tags does not create two copies of the variable. You can declare a variable for each slider by giving them different names.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Round Range Slider</h1>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" 
               class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" 
               class="slider" id="myRange1">
        <p>Value1: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
<head>
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
       output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }

    var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
    var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;

    slider1.oninput = function() {
        output1.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Better yet, use a loop:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Round Range Slider</h1>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" 
               class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" 
               class="slider" id="myRange1">
        <p>Value1: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
<head>
<script>
    let sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slidecontainer");
    sliders.forEach(slideContainer => {
        // Get a reference to the children of the current container.
        let sliderChild = slideContainer.children[0];
        let spanChild = slideContainer.children[1].children[0];

        // Attach an event listener to each slider.
        sliderChild.oninput = () => spanChild.innerText = sliderChild.value;

        // Initialize the label.
        spanChild.innerText = sliderChild.value;
    });
</script>
</head>
```